# How can I add static values in a column in grafana/influxdb

Tags: jmeter, grafana, influxdb

I'm using grafana, influxdb and jmeter. I have this table.
 [image]
 I need to add a column that says "Base Line" with a value different for each request name. I have tried the following:
 - Grafana does not seem to have a way to add static values for columns, or a query equivalent of sql for "select 'value' as 'columnName'"
 - I tried creating a new time series for static data (base lines) and do a join of the results from jmeter with the series I created, but I get this error:

> error parsing query: found AS, expected ;

I'm having a hard time trying to create an extra column with fixed data for each request... my last resort is to modify or create a jmeter plugin for that matter, but before going for that, there might be something I could be missing.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution I can think of is adding a [Dummy Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-dummy-sampler-the-ultimate-guide) which will be doing nothing but "sleeping" for specified amount of time which is your "baseline".

[image: JMeter Baseline Dummy Sampler]

JMeter's [Backend Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Backend_Listener) will collect this sampler metrics and you will either see a straight horizontal line identifying your baseline in the chart or the baseline value in the table or will be able to aggregate as a vertical column.

You can install Dummy Sampler using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

Comment: This would generate a new row in the table, what I need is another column with a default value.